# Finding the next element divisible by 4

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a list of elements like so;

```
<div></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="test2"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="test3"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="test4"></div>
<div></div>
```

And essentially I need to figure out what is the next element relative to the selector whose order is divisible by four, counting from the beginning. If there aren't enough elements relative to selector, the last element would be returned. Ergo, I'd get the following sort of results;

```
$(".test").nextFour().after("Hello");
// or $(".test2").nextFour().after("Hello");

<div></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="test2"></div>
Hello
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="test3"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="test4"></div>
<div></div>
```

```
$(".test3").nextFour().addClass("hello");

<div></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="test2"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="test3"></div>
<div class="hello"></div>
<div class="test4"></div>
<div></div>
```

```
$(".test4").nextFour().css("color", "red");

<div></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="test2"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="test3"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="test4"></div>
<div style="color: red;"></div>
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: ^^ His link is irrelevant

Comment: @Joum: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: is this better?: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

Comment: @Joum [see here](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: @Zeaklous Oh really? Why is that?

Comment: @Joum just see it you will know it.

Comment: Just because you have an opinion about the information, it does not make it innacurate. It is a perfectly valid pseudo-selector as @Martijn below just proved. If you want to make a point, argue it intead of pasting a link to an opinion based site (now matter how valid it may be).

Comment: I've just removed it. I thought the question was how to move 4, but I think Emphram wants to move to the first items dividable by 4 (to starting from to that would be 4, not 6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var elem = $(selector);
var idx = elem.index() + 1;

var target = elem.parent().children().eq(idx + 4-(idx%4)-1);

if (!target.length)
    target = elem.parent().children().last();
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/zZVax/1/

Comment: I like this method, only the modulum method (`%`) isnt very fast. If this would be implemented large scale, it would slow things down

Comment: It's actually very fast compared to most methods one would use in jQuery. It won't cause any perceptible difference.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use it as a function after a selecter, you could prototype something:

```
// Here is a untested example:
$.fn.nextFour = function (arguments){
    // As suggested by Crazy Train:
    return $(this).parent().children().eq(idx + 4-(idx%4)-1); // -1 to correct zero-based index
}
```

I've changed my answer after Crazytrain pointed out the question was not to move 4 elements, but to move to the next item dividable by 4. Starting from 2 that would make 4, not 6

---

I'll keep the following selector to show how to move 4 spots, but it isnt the asnwer to this question:
 CSS has a nth selector which is usable in jQuery:

```
$('div:nth-child(4n+'+startElement+')').css({background: pink});
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. OP doesn't want to move ahead four siblings. OP wants to move ahead to the next one that is divisible by four.

Comment: Yes, misread it, I've updated my prototype part. Seems like the css nth-child is off too, removed it. Would you mind if I add your last-solution? I dont want to copy your answer, but I can only upvote yours once :P Would be a shame it OP missed this

Answer (score 1):

In complement to *Crazy Train*, you can create a jQuery method to use it like in your examples :

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.nextFour = function() {
      elem = this.parent().children().eq(this.index() + 3-(this.index()%4));
      return elem.length ? elem : this.parent().children().last();
   }; 
})( jQuery );
```

**edit :** note it has to be `+ 3` to work as you expected. I also added a piece of code to return the last element if none has been found.

See the **[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gwTVK/)**

To be more flexible, you can also pass a "step" as parameter :

```
$.fn.nextStep = function(step) {
    elem = this.parent().children().eq(this.index() + step -1 -(this.index()%step));
    return elem.length ? elem : this.parent().children().last();
};
```

And use it like so :

```
$(".test3").nextStep(4).addClass("hello");
```

**[Enhanced method demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gwTVK/1/)**